# Inject AngularJS 1.2 $location service into controller not working in PhoneGap 3.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-7-emulator

In a Windows Phone 7.1 emulator with PhoneGap 3.0 and AngularJS 1.2, why does this not work:

```
angulargap.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location',
function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.message = "AngularJS!";
}]);
```

Error message:

```
ERROR:Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$injector/cdep?p0=
```

While this works:

```
angulargap.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
    $scope.message = "AngularJS!";
}]);
```

What is going wrong with injecting the $location service in this specific scenario? All works great in Chrome and Internet Explorer in a desktop browser. But it does not work in the Windows Phone 7 device emulator, nor on the physical device itself.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with your injection of $location into $scope.  Could you try removing `$scope.$location = $location` and see if you still have the problem?  So we can isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi @KayakDave, the issue is the same after removing that line. That specific piece of code is from an example that works great in the browser.

Comment: Interesting problem.  In case you haven't seen, here's details on your error: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector:cdep    The next thing I'd be tempted to try is to put this all inside a module in order to control the scope more tightly.  But that's just me guessing.

Comment: I see you are using a module- oops.  But I have another idea- how about renaming your function parameter $location to something else.  Keep your first '$location' after the square brackets as is.  But change the second one to something like "renamed$location" and use the renamed version within your code.  This should keep minification  working but might address the injector trying to inject $location in twice.  But it's just a theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it guys ... There is a substantial amount of issues for the AngularJS/PhoneGap/WindowsPhone combination. This one was solved by https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2303?source=cc#issuecomment-20770025.

Essentially, because windows phone uses a weird protocol prefix with a single forward slash `(x-wmapp0:/)`, the $location initializer goes nuts and that triggers an error which seamingly exposes itself in this weird error message, completely unrelated to the error :-(

I'm about to propose a pull-request on this fix to the AngularJS repo on GitHub.